# React Native useEffect confusion

Tags: react-native, use-effect, react-native-calendars

I'm building a project overview app and I'm using React-Native-calendar. I also created two buttons to filter the calendar. I'm fetching the data(API), I'm mapping the data to an object for "markedDates". Everything works appropriately as it should. Now the onPress of each button assigns the object to a state to filter. That works as well. What doesn't work is that those markedDates, that for sure come in correctly, are not shown when the app loads. They are shown however when I click on a button, but not on load. The rough code order:

```
const [meineTermine, setMeineTermine] = useState([]);
const [dates, setdates] = useState([]);
const [markedFinal, setMarkedFinal] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
   const unsubscribe = db.collection("Dates").onSnapshot(snapshot => (
        setdates(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
        })))
    ))
    const filter = db.collection("Dates").where("involv", "==", auth.currentUser.displayName).onSnapshot(snapshot => (
        setMeineTermine(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data(),
        })))
    ))
    return unsubscribe && filter;
  }, [])

let markedDayAll = {};
let markedDayMe = {};

{dates.map(({data: {anfang}}) => (
    markedDayAll[anfang] = {
      selected: true
  }
  ))}

{meineTermine.map(({data: {anfang}}) => (
    markedDayMe[anfang] = {
        selected: true
  }
))}


<View>
   <Button onPress={setMarkedFinal(Object.assign({}, markedDayAll))}/>
   <Button onPress={setMarkedFinal(Object.assign({}, markedDayMe))}/>
   <CalendarList
      markedDates={ markedFinal }
      onDayPress={() => navigation.navigate("ViewDate")}
   />
</View>
```

I tried to map the data to objects in useEffect which didn't work. I also tried to have a default value in state, which also didn't work. What am I missing? In which order do I need to set the code up, since it works, just not on load. Where do I need to implement the "setMarkedFinal" so it shows on load?

Comment: You will have to show the code.

Comment: I updated the code. Where do I need to put "setMarkedFinal" so that it show the data on load?

Comment: What should `markedFinal` be on load?
`onPress` takes a lambda, but you supplied it with a function call. So basically on load `setMarkedFinal(Object.assign({}, markedDayAll)` will be evaluated and setMarkedFinal to {}.

Comment: Yes, right now, I haven't declared markedFinal, but I tried to insert "setMarkedFinal(Object.assign({}, markedDayAll)" in various positions (inital value of state, useEffect etc.) with no success. useEffect isn't working out, because the data isn't mapped to anything at that time, and then the data gets mapped and once its mapped I need to use "setMarkedFinal....". Do I use another useEffect for this?

Comment: What I'm saying is that onPress requires a lambda. So you write it like `onPress={() => setMarkedFinal(markedDayAll)}`.

Comment: `onPress={setMarkedFinal(markedDayAll)}` will call setMarkedFinal (setting it immediately to nothing), then you will have `onPress={undefined}` as your button handler.